# Elastic Beanstalk optionsettings file keep getting overwritten with default parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While trying to setup an elastic beanstalk worker application using the command line tools (`eb` tools), my configuration file (`optionsettings.MyApp-env`) gets overwritten when I start/update/stop the environment.

These are the steps to reproduce:

1. Using the CLI tools' command `eb init` I've created a new application in Elastic Beanstalk.
2. The `config` file in the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder had the following line:
   `OptionSettingFile=/Users/doron/projects/workers/my-worker/.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.MyWorkerName-dev`
3. After running `eb start` for the first time, that file was created with some values.
4. I went ahead and changed its contents according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html so it'll be configured as I want (environment parameters, autoscaling servers amount, etc...).
5. To apply the changes I've tried the following:

   1. Update the existing environment with `eb update`.
   2. Terminate the existing environment with `eb stop` and build it from scratch with `eb start`.

   In both cases the `optionsettings` file get changed after running the command (`update` or `start`).

   The new content of the file looks more like the vanilla version I got after calling the first `eb start` with all sorts of configuration parameters that I added - removed completely.

Is there another way of configuring the environment (not the software on the machine, but the configuration that exists in the console - instance type, regions, autoscaling, rotating updates, etc...) ?

Comment: I assume you did git commit after changing the config file? Do the contents of the file on the file system get changed? That's surprising.  Did you try git add .ebextensions/yourfile.config, then git commit followed by git aws.push?

Comment: I'm not talking about the committed .ebextensions folder, but rather on the not-committed .elasticbeanstalk folder.

Comment: Whatever is explained in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html should go in .ebextensions/yourfile.config? Are you saying you put it in .elasticbeanstalk? That file should not be modified manually. That is autogenerated by eb. You should add contents to .ebextensions.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Actually slight correction on my side, I think you can edit your .elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings file.  Just running eb update should not overwrite the file. To answer your question yes there is another way to edit the configuration using ebextensions config file. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html
But still it seems surprising that just running 'eb update' overwrote your config file.

Answer (score 7):

I realise that this is an old thread but in case anyone comes across this, as I did, then check out this thread on the AWS forums for Elasticbeanstalk https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=395052#395052
It explains how settings set in the *.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.* file are set using the API in such a way that they can't be changed later, unlike those set in the *.ebextensions/*.config* files.

Also, in an incredibly annoying move, the optionsettings file will often set some settings in it which you want to set in the .config file however it automatically re-creates the optionsettings file when running eb start and there's very little that seems possible. This makes using the eb command line tools close to impossible to use if you want to change something like the WSGIPath.